# Image blurring using gaussian low pass filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blur, gaussian

I'm trying to blur a grayscale image using Gaussian low pass filter( 5*5 kernal).I tried the following code.

```
I = imread('Lena.png');
G = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],2);
Ig = imfilter(I,G,'same');
imshow(Ig);
```

But I'm getting an error in file 'meshgrid.m' as follows.

```
Error: File: meshgrid.m Line: 1 Column: 5
The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
Error in fspecial (line 145)
[x,y] = meshgrid(-siz(2):siz(2),-siz(1):siz(1));
Error in Untitled2 (line 2)
G = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],2);
```

I'm not understanding what the error is.Can anyone help me please.The input image that I used is uploaded below('Lena.png').Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It works for me perfectly. You may not have the file `Lena.png` properly saved... Additionally: You may want to show `Ig`instead of `G`. `imshow(Ig)`.

Comment: If your .m file is named "meshgrid" that may be the source of the problem since this is a built-in function in MATLAB. Try changing it to something else.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code off the internet? You might have copied a `'` quote character that is a different unicode char from the one matlab expects. If you pasted the code, try typing it out yourself from scratch. Also at which line are you getting the error (i.e. please print the entire error)?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yeah.It is saved correctly.I'm using Matlab R2012a version.Is it because of the version problem?

Comment: @Benoit_11 "meshgrid.m" is not the  file name.

Comment: Ok, but in the question it's written "But I'm getting an error in file 'meshgrid.m' as follows."

Comment: @Dan Still I'm getting the same error sir.Updated the complete error

Comment: @Benoit_11 I'm also stucked over there.Updated the entire error

Comment: Weird. Do you have some function/script that you named fspecial?

Comment: Have you altered either `fspecial` or `meshgrid`? Or written your own functions with those names? Otherwise I wonder if it's a locale issue - these guys mention that same error (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Error_Messages#Other_miscellaneous_errors) as occuring when you use a character such as `ä`.

Comment: These guys (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100503-why-do-i-receive-error-messages-when-attempting-to-use-matlab-7-0-4-r14sp2-as-an-automation-server) say that you can get that error if you install matlab in a folder that contains spaces in it's name...

Comment: Here is one where an invisible special character got in the way: http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54092-when-i-use-deploytool-error-the-input-character-is-not-valid-in-matlab-statements-or-expressions One thing you could try (but don't mess this up! Backup first!!!) Is to delete that line out of `meshgrid` (type `edit meshgrid` in the command line) and also make sure to delete ALL spaces and linebreaks before and after and then manually retype it and save... in particular, check if your first line in `meshgrid.m` doesn't start `function [xx,yy` etc...

Comment: Your `meshgrid.m` file is probably unintentionally edited.  Here's my version of `meshgrid.m`:  http://pastie.org/pastes/9835398/text .  Try copying this text and overwriting your `meshgrid.m` file with this.  Obviously, save a backup of your `meshgrid.m` file before you decide to do this.

Comment: @Celine - No problem.  closing your question as it's due to a typo.