# Low pass filter on image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to write a MATLAB function that takes in an image and a frequency, performs a low pass filter on that image (keeping only the frequencies lower than the provided frequency), and returns the new image.

How do I go about doing this? Right now I have the following:

```
function newImage = lowPass(image, freq)
% apply a low pass filter on an image and output the result

Fs = 44100;
eps = 0.000000001;
transformed = fft2(image);

for i = ceil(freq * size(image,1) / Fs):size(image,1)
    for j = ceil(freq * size(image,2) / Fs):size(image,2)
        transformed(i,j) = 0;
    end
end

newImage = abs(ifft2(transformed))/256;
newImage = newImage / (max(max(max(newImage))) + eps);

end
```

However, my output images appear blue and do not make any sense. Now that the last two lines of my code (the ones that involve modifying newImage) are done to scale the colors to the correct values.

What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm surprised that MATLAB does not seem to have a function that does this automatically.

Comment: Could you post a sample image, please.

Comment: Related: [Image blurring using gaussian low pass filter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27985769/2545927)

Comment: @kkuilla not exactly the same.  That post is doing it in spatial domain, but a good step in the right direction.

Comment: The concept of a single frequency for a 2D image doesn't make any sense.  When you go to images, you have both horizontal frequencies and vertical frequencies.  The concept of 44100 Hz for an image is nonsense.  Either way, the answer below is the right way to go.

Comment: @rayryeng I know. I said related. Not the same. There is quite a lot of material out there on how to do it. Unfortunately, I have to go and sleep so it is all yours....  :-)

Comment: Something else I noticed is that you appear to be using `fft2` on a 3-channel image.  You could use `fftn` I suppose but it would probably be more straightforward to do what you're doing on each color channel separately.  If all you're doing is zeroing out high frequency bins, you shouldn't need to normalize the magnitude of `newImage`.  The DC gain will remain unchanged. You also shouldn't need to use `abs()` to get the magnitude because the `ifft2` result will not be complex if done correctly (assuming your input image is not complex).

Comment: @surgical_tubing `fft2` uses `fftn` under the hood. If you read the source code, it applies `fft2` to each slice independently so its use for colour images is fine here. The 2D FFT is calculated for each colour channel separately as a result, though this behaviour is certainly undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

You are not preserving the symmetry of the 2D fft when you only zero out one quadrant.  DC is at index `1` and Nyquist is at index `size(image)/2+1` so you need to make complimentary changes to relative to Nyquist.

```
%generate signal
A=rand(8,8)
[m,n]=size(A)

% FFT
A_fft = fft2(A)
%zero out a symmetric region of frequencies 
A_fft((m/2+1) + (-2:2) , : ) = 0
A_fft( :  , (n/2+1) + (-2:2) ) = 0

% inverse FFT
A_mod = ifft2(A_fft)

%observe that DC is preserved, signal is still real
mean(A(:))
mean(A_mod(:))
```

Comment: This is what I was gonna suggest.  To make things easier, I was going to shift the frequencies so DC is in the middle using `fftshift`.  It makes the zeroing easier.  Either way, +1.

Comment: Can you explain how your approach is a low pass filter? Can you write a function that takes in an image and a frequency and outputs an image with all the high frequency components removed?

Comment: It's an example of a lowpass filter that zeros out the highest frequency of image A (vertical  and horizontal Nyquist at `m/2+1` and `n/2+1` respectively).  In addition to zeroing out Nyquist it zeros out the next highest frequencies in the range Nyquist-2 to Nyquist+2 (the `+(-2:2)` part).  In this example the  frequency range is hard coded. You have to convert the frequency in Hz to the corresponding FFT bin indices using the sampling frequency and abstract it to a function just as you did in your question.